# Java 7 - Graphics2D.setFont() and Graphics2D.setColor() is being overridden by defaults when Printing.

Tags: java, swing, printing, graphics2d

I have a program that draws to the a panel and also prints.  When drawing to the Canvas the renderer produces the correct output.  However when drawing to the print method the font is overridden with a default font.
Please see below two images displaying the out put.
[image: Canvas or Screen Output]

[image: Printed PDF output]

The code to the specific areas are in my Visualise2D.class
The Renderers for the Canvas and the Print are the same they both call the Visualise2D.class.

Some Code from Visualise2D

```
    public void paintSurfaceTimes(Graphics2D gTimes, SurfaceConnector s, Dummy d, Color c, Rectangle2D bounds,double scale, double enhanceTie, double enhance ){
    gTimes.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    FontMetrics fm = gTimes.getFontMetrics();
    double hEdge = (UnitConvert.pixelsToMeters(LiteTieTRIAL.averageSize));
    double x1 =((d.getEasting() - bounds.getX()));
    double y1 = (bounds.getHeight() + bounds.getY() - d.getNorthing());

    if (d instanceof Hole) {
        hEdge = (UnitConvert.pixelsToMeters(((Hole) d).getDiameter()* enhance)/2);
    }
    else
        hEdge = (UnitConvert.pixelsToMeters(LiteTieTRIAL.averageSize * enhance)/2);

    x1 =((d.getEasting() - bounds.getX()));
    y1 = (bounds.getHeight() + bounds.getY() - d.getNorthing());

    gTimes.setColor(c);
    gTimes.setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
    fm = gTimes.getFontMetrics();
    gTimes.drawString((dec0P.format(s.getTime())), 
            (int)((x1+hEdge*Math.cos(180))*scale - fm.getStringBounds(dec0P.format(s.getTime()), gTimes).getWidth()),
            (int)((y1 - hEdge*Math.sin(0))*scale+ fm.getStringBounds(dec0P.format(s.getTime()), gTimes).getHeight()));
}
```

And some Code from paintComponent(Graphics g) in my getCanvas() method

```
                    //Draws SurfaceTimes
                if(surfaceTimesOnOffButton.isSelected())    {
                    try {
                        getSurfaceTimes();
                    } catch (NegativeNumberException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for(Pattern tempPat: world.getPatternList().values()){
                        for(SurfaceConnector sc: tempPat.getSurfaceList().values()){
                            //                          boolean isSelected = sc == selected || (selected instanceof Collection<?> && ((Collection<?>)selected).contains(sc));   

                            if(sc.getTo() instanceof Dummy ){
                                renderer.paintSurfaceTimes(g2, sc, sc.getTo(), colourTimes, bounds, Zoom.getScalingFactor()* UnitConvert.metersToPixels(1), enhanceTie, enhance);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

The only differences between the canvas drawing code and the printable is:
getCanvas() code below...

```
Visualise2D renderer = new Visualise2D();
            @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

LiteTiePrinter.class

```
public class LiteTiePrinter implements Printable {
```

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

```
// We have only one page, and 'page'
// is zero-based
if (page > 0) {
     return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

// Now we perform our rendering
Visualise2D renderer = new Visualise2D();
```

Any help is appreciated as to why the output on fonts is different. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to anyone reading this. I thought I'd share my 15hrs of searching the internet and stack overflow to find an answer to my own question.  I just found one and tested a suggestion out.  And it worked.

I choose to use the answer supplied by ***user456837***.  *If I had enough points I'd up vote this user.*

The answer was to supplement the **drawString()** with **drawGlyphVector()**.  It worked!

```
//GET THE FONTMETRICS
        FontMetrics fm = h2.getFontMetrics();
        //GET THE DIAMETER OF THE HOLE
        double hEdge = (UnitConvert.pixelsToMeters(hole.getDiameter()));
        // GET THE LOCATION OF THE HOLE
        double x1 =((hole.getEasting() - bounds.getX()));
        double y1 = (bounds.getHeight() + bounds.getY() - hole.getNorthing());
        //SET THE COLOUR OF THE TEXT
        h2.setColor(AMETHYST);
        //SET THE FONT TO USE
        h2.setFont(new Font("Monaco", Font.BOLD, 8));
        //USING - DRAWGLYPHVECTOR() TO OVERCOME THE PRINTING ISSUE RELATED TO THE OSX PORT OF JAVA7 - MAY NOT NEED THIS WITH FUTURE UPDATES.
        h2.drawGlyphVector(
                h2.getFont().createGlyphVector(h2.getFontRenderContext(), 
                dec1P.format(hole.getHoleLength())),
                (int)((x1+hEdge*Math.cos(300))*scale)- (fm.stringWidth(dec1P.format(hole.getHoleLength()))/2),  
                (int)((y1 + (hEdge *enhance*1.1)/2)*scale) +(fm.getHeight()/2) +pixelOffset
                );
        
        /*//USING - DRAWSTRING() DOESN'T WORK IN JAVA 7 ON MAC OSX
        h2.drawString(
                (dec1P.format(hole.getHoleLength())),   
                (int)((x1+hEdge*Math.cos(300))*scale)- (fm.stringWidth(dec1P.format(hole.getHoleLength()))/2),  
                (int)((y1 + (hEdge *enhance*1.1)/2)*scale) +(fm.getHeight()/2) +pixelOffset
                );
*/
```

I hope that this helps anyone searching for the same issue.  Also I suggest you read Stephane Grenier's blog on the issue. It mentions in one of the blog comments that this is not evident in Java 7u40... so maybe I'd be best to upgrade…?

**PLEASE READ THE LINK BELOW**

[Printing issue on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466060/java-app-on-mac-os-x-not-printing-fonts-correctly?rq=1)